# Expressing $(a \ast b)^{-1}$ in terms of $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ where $a,b \in G$, $G$ is a group under operation "$\ast$".

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was asked to express $(a \ast b)^{-1}$ in terms of $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ where $a,b \in G$, $G$ is a group under operation "$\ast$". I tried it this way.

$${(a \ast b)^{-1} \ast (a \ast b) = e}$$
\begin{equation}
{(a \ast b)^{-1} = \frac {e}{(a \ast b)}} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now dealing with only R.H.S of the above equation we have-
$${\frac {e}{a \ast b}}$$
$$={\frac {a^{-1} \ast e}{a^{-1} \ast a \ast b}}$$
$$={\frac {(a^{-1} \ast e)}{(a^{-1} \ast a) \ast b}}$$
$$={\frac {(a^{-1})}{(e \ast b)}}$$
$$={\frac {(a^{-1} \ast b^{-1})}{(e\ast b)\ast b^{-1}}}$$
$$={\frac {(a^{-1} \ast b^{-1})}{e\ast (b\ast b^{-1})}}$$
$$={\frac {(a^{-1} \ast b^{-1})}{e\ast e}}$$
$$={\frac {(a^{-1} \ast b^{-1})}{e}}$$
Using this result in (1) we have
$$(a \ast b)^{-1} = \frac{(a^{-1} \ast b^{-1})}{e}$$
$$(a \ast b)^{-1} \ast e =(a^{-1} \ast b^{-1})$$
$$(a \ast b)^{-1}=(a^{-1} \ast b^{-1}) \tag{2}$$

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Don’t use fractions in group theory. $\frac{a}{b}$ could either mean $a b^{-1}$ or $b^{-1}a$ which frequently are different. It also causes you to make errors of the form $ab^{-1}=xa (xb)^{-1}$ which isn’t true.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for guiding me through this. I will remember this and here after won't use fractions while dealing with groups. Thank you again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an analogy to think about this.

$a$ represents the operation of wearing socks. $a^{-1}$ represents taking socks off.

$b$ represents the operation of wearing shoes. $b^{-1}$ represents taking shoes off.

$a * b$ is wearing socks and then wearing shoes. What would the inverse of this be?

Can you find out the inverse of $a * b$, in terms of $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, now?

Comment: thank you for sharing this information. Now I can solve this easily. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are somewhat new to group theoretic thinking, so I will present a proof of this claim. I suggest you pay close attention to how it is written, compared to how you are used to performing arithmetic.

*Proof:* We claim that $b^{-1}a^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$. To justify this, we recall that the inverse of a group element $\alpha$ is a $\beta$ so that $\beta\alpha = \alpha\beta = e$. It follows that *(this is the key logical step)* to prove our claim, **we must show that the elements given satisfy the relation defining the inverse**. Indeed:

$$(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab) = b^{-1}(a^{-1}a)b = b^{-1}b = e$$

and

$$(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = a(bb^{-1})a^{-1} = aa^{-1} = e$$

So $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is $ab$'s inverse, which is precisely what we claimed. $\square$

One thing to point out is that in the past when you had access to nice properties like commutativity and well-defined division, when you wanted to show that a formula like $xy =1$ holds, you simply divide by $y$ and perform further arithmetical manipulations until you reach the desired form. In general groups, you cannot do this: instead you have to think a bit more flexibly, and use the definitions you have been given. Rather than starting with $xy=1$ and working backwards, instead you need to cook up the right element and work forwards to show that $xy=1$, which is exactly what I did in the proof.

Comment: It is true that I am new to group theory. Thank you for sharing your valuable time to explain this. I will try to process my thoughts in the way you have described and if I have further queries, I will ask again.